# Chromadb returning a Distance other than 0

Tags: chromadb

The code below creates a chromadb and adds 10 sentences to it. Then I am querying for sentence no 1. I was hoping to get a distance of 0.0 instead I get `-2.220446049250313e-16`

Code

```
import chromadb
from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions

embedding_function = embedding_functions.DefaultEmbeddingFunction()
client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="./db")

sentences = [
  "COVID-19 Vaccination Rates Reach 70% Milestone in the United States",
  "Stock Market Surges to Record Highs as Economy Recovers",
  "NASA's Perseverance Rover Discovers Ancient Signs of Life on Mars",
  "World Leaders Gather for Climate Summit to Address Global Warming",
  "New Study Shows Link Between Exercise and Mental Health Improvement",
  "Record-Breaking Heatwave Hits Europe, Sparks Concerns About Climate Change",
  "Major Cybersecurity Breach Exposes Sensitive Data of Millions of Users",
  "Scientists Make Breakthrough in Fusion Energy, Promising Clean Power",
  "UN Report Highlights Alarming Decline in Biodiversity Worldwide",
  "SpaceX Successfully Launches Crewed Mission to the International Space Station"
]
ids = list(map(str, list(range(1, len(sentences) + 1))))
metadatas = [{'type': 'news', 'source': 'nytimes'} for i in range(len(sentences))]

collection = client.get_or_create_collection(name="headlines", embedding_function=embedding_function, metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine"})
collection.add(ids=ids, documents=sentences, metadatas=metadatas)


q_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="./db")
query = sentences[0]
q_collection = q_client.get_collection("headlines")
results = q_collection.query(query_texts=[query], include=["documents", "distances", "metadatas"], n_results=1)
print(results)
```

This outputs

```
{'ids': [['1']], 'distances': [[-2.220446049250313e-16]], 'metadatas': [[{'source': 'nytimes', 'type': 'news'}]], 'embeddings': None, 'documents': [['COVID-19 Vaccination Rates Reach 70% Milestone in the United States']]}
```

I was hoping the distance to be 0. Can someone help me explain this.

Comment: This is a veeery small value (i.e. -2.2x10^-16) to me it looks like a rounding issue from when the distance is calculated. Maybe you could round it to some fixed number of decimals?